# Why is this redemptionPeriod so long?

Tags: domain

There is a domain i want, using who.is i see "Expiration Date: 2010-11-28" status is redemptionPeriod. Why hasnt it become available yet? I did notice a "Last Update Date:  2011-01-09". Does this mean? The other domain does not have a last update date.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Name registrars often tend to hold domains for a period after they expire in order to give the previous owner a second chance at renewing them.  Note, this isn't something they do out of the goodness of their heart.  The domain registrars add a pretty hefty surcharge (sometimes upwards of $100us or more) for this service offering.

More money for them if they get the previous owner to renew the domain and pay their surcharge, than letting it expire and get registered by someone else.